# Bind a textbox to a property class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, thread-safety

I have these :

- A Form with a Label on it
- A class "Business"
- A class "TimerHelper"

I'd like when I update the property `MyTime`, update the textbox too

My "Business" class look like this :

```
public class MyBusinessClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void MakeSound(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // I change MyTime here
    }   
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private int myTime;
    public int MyTime
    {
        get { return myTime; }
        set
        {
            myTime= value;
            InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyTime"));
        }
    }
    public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

The "TimerHelper" look like this :

```
public class TimerHelper
{
    private Timer _timer;
    public void Run()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(1000);
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MyBusinessClass.MakeSound);
    }
}
```

In the forms, I tried this :

```
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", new MyBusinessClass(), "MyTime");
```

but I get an exception in the method "InvokePropertyChanged"
[image]

I tried this :

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { myTextBox.Text = new MyBusinessClass().MyTime; });
```

but the textBox is never updated

Comment: I can not really understand the relation between business class and time helper. can you tell the scenario?

Comment: It's a kind of metronome. I start a tempo, x sec, the MyBusinessClass.MakeSound() method is called and this methode will update a field 'MyTime'. When the field is updated, I'd like update the TextBox of the form

Comment: Where are you making the call Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { myTextBox.Text = new MyBusinessClass().MyTime; });?

Comment: @Blam in Forms.cs in button click event sed to launch the counter. It's after InitializeComponent()

Comment: So not clear. sed  What counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer there :
[A generic asynchronous INotifyPropertyChanged helper](http://www.claassen.net/geek/blog/2007/07/generic-asynchronous.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is you are trying to update the text box through databibding from other thread.
I mean, you're using System.Timers.Timer class which invokes Elapsed event in a threadpool.
Databinding fails updating the control because you're changing your business class in that threadpool.
You should change of thread context in the Elapsed event handler and update your business model in the main thread (where text box was created).

```
public class TimerHelper
{    
   private Timer _timer;
   public void Run()
   {
      _timer = new Timer(1000);
      _timer.Enabled = true;
      _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimerElapsed);
   }
}

void OnTimerElapsed (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myTextBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        myTextBox.Invoke(MyBusinessClass.MakeSound);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not see where you are setting the value of `MyTime` (I assume it is in `MakeSound`?), you are setting the value of `MyTime` on a thread other than the UI thread. You are probably using the `System.Timers.Timer` class, which does not execute the event handler on the UI thread. If you want to use `System.Timers.Timer` and make changes to the UI in its `ElapsedEventHandler` delegate, you need to make use of the `SynchronizingObject` property on the timer. See this MSDN article for more information: [Comparing the Timer Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Comment: Indeed I change MyTime in MakeSound()